# Trying to create a network that focuses on node impact

Tags: matlab, visualization, graph-theory

I am trying to create a network that visualizes data from the linked webpage. I want it to look similar to the picture on the website, but also display weighted edges, and focus on which of the nodes in the network is the most important and impacts the connectivity of the network the most. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

https://networks.skewed.de/net/crime
[image: crime network]

I have tried scripts like the following. None of them have accomplished what I need, or rather I fail to understand what I need to include.

```
`% Assuming you have a table named 'myTable' with columns 'Nodes', 'Edges', 'MeanDegree', and             'StandardDeviationOfDegrees'
% Replace this with your actual table and column names

% Create a graph object from the table
G = graph(myTable.Nodes, myTable.Edges);

% Plot the network
figure;
plot(G, 'Layout', 'force', 'NodeLabel', G.Nodes.Name);
title('Network Visualization from Table');

% Display node attributes
table(G.Nodes.Name, G.Nodes.MeanDegree, G.Nodes.StandardDeviationOfDegrees, ...
'VariableNames', {'Node', 'MeanDegree', 'StandardDeviationOfDegrees'})
```

---

```
% Load your network data and create the graph (replace with your actual data)
% For example, assuming you have a graph object G:
% G = graph(nodes, edges);

% Calculate the degree of each node
nodeDegrees = degree(G);

% Find the node with the highest degree
[maxDegree, maxDegreeNode] = max(nodeDegrees);

% Display the results
fprintf('Node with the highest degree: %d\n', maxDegreeNode);
fprintf('Degree of the node: %d\n', maxDegree);

`% Plot the network (optional)
figure;
plot(G, 'Layout', 'force');
title('Network Visualization');
xlabel('X-axis');
ylabel('Y-axis');
grid on;``
```

Comment: You’re creating graphs, not networks. A graph can represent a network, but the words are not synonymous. Using the proper name for what you’re doing will help the right people find your question. Please [edit] your post!

Comment: And, more importantly, please update your post to describe what the problem is with your current code, why your current results are lacking, and what you would like to see instead. As it stands. It would be hard to answer your question without making a lot of guesses.

Comment: "(The nodes that)  impacts the connectivity of the (graph) the most"  This is a vague requirement and so almost impossible to know what you really mean by it.  Best Guess: you want to find the nodes, that if removed, will split the graph into an ( increased ) number of unconnected components.  The term for such nodes is 'articulation points'.  They are found by implementing Tarjan's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component